# Is there any explanation for the Rinnegan being on people?

Tags: naruto

So, I came across this scene in the anime, and was confused about the Rinnegan.
[image]
That is [Lord Tenji](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tenji) being wrapped up by the God Tree when he asks [Kaguya](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kaguya) about who she was.
Episode 460

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is due to the effect of Infinite Tsukuyomi.

Once it is cast:

> All those who fall under its gaze are trapped in the genjutsu, with the Rinnegan's design appearing in their eyes to represent its influence.

Just like when you can see the Sharingan pattern in Kyuubi's eyes when it was under Obito's control during the attack on Konoha.

Source:

[Infinite Tsukuyomi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Tsukuyomi)

Comment: When Sasuke used his Rinnegan to put all of the Tailed Beasts under his control, his Rinnegan also reflected on their eyes.